# Javascript triangle alternating underline numbers

Tags: javascript

I had an assignment earlier today that I couldn't seem to get through. The requirements where to make a triangle using loops. It had to look like this:

```
2 
2 3 
2 3 4 
2 3 
2
```

Two prompt boxes asked appeared asking to input 2 numbers and based on those numbers the triangle would create. The first number had to be smaller than the second number for this to work. Even numbers would be underlined. The problem is that the code I wrote only outputs a long line instead of the pyramid shape. Is there anyway to fix this?

```
<script>
var number1 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"));
var number2 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a larger number"));

if (isNaN(number1) || isNaN(number2))
{
    document.write("Please enter a valid number" + "<br>");
}
else if(number1 > number2)
{
    document.write("Number 2 must be bigger than number 1");
};

for (var i = number1; i <= number2; i++){
    for (var j = number2; j >= i; j--)
    {
        if (j%2==0)
        {
            document.write("<u>" + j + "</u>");
        }
        else
        {
            document.write(j + " ");
        }

        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's your question? Don't just dump a bunch of code at us, explain what you're having trouble with.

Comment: think you need an `HTML table`...?!?

Comment: The code i've written ends up in a line shape instead of the pyramid. I can't think of a way for the break to execute one number in after each row (ex) 1 <br> 1 2 <br>